Zero-inflated data in an RDA
I am trying to use an RDA model to find how strongly certain habitat variables are correlated with the abundance of bullfrog.
rda_b2 = rda(formula = d_final_scaled$BF_Conc_TF ~ mean_PVI_E + Refugia + Shallow_BL + Oxygen,
              data = d_final_scaled)

However, half of our ponds did not have any bullfrog. This has created a very right-skewed dataset, thereby violating the normality assumption of an RDA. Unsurprisingly, a Shapiro test revealed a p-value = 4.786e-07 for the residuals of my model.
I tried a log transformation log10(d_final$BF_Conc + 1) and also scaled my data. However I came to realize that this was perhaps a tad pointless, because I believe no matter what kind of transformation I use, the '0' observations will skew the data all the same. Is there anything I can do so I can use this dataset for an RDA?
Below is a simple histogram showing my log-transformed and scaled bullfrog data

PS: I read something about using a zero-inflated model and then using the residuals of that model in my RDA, but I don't fully trust the source nor pretend to be familiar with such models. Is this a valid option?
Thanks for reading this far!

Hi Torrin, I've flagged your question as more appropriate for stats.stackexchange.com, because it is primarily about statistical modelling rather than computer code

Btw, have you looked into hurdle models?

@CaptainHat ok, thank you. I will repost the question on that website then

Why are you using rda to model abundance? rda is  an ordination technique for analysing community data matrices. If there's no other species in your data and it's just the abundance of a single bull frog species you should use a glm
